# Accessing AWS Lambda from Aurora RDS trigger using lambda_async?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-aurora

Version: 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2

i am trying to link lambda function when my RDS get inserted using **lambda_async**. but was not able to reach it with an error

**#63996 - Lambda API returned error: Missing IAM Credentials for specified aws_default_lambda_role**

i have followed each and every step carefully but getting above error. :(

i have followed the documentation at
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html

and

[Call AWS Lambda from Aurora RDS Stored Procedure Permissions Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659145/call-aws-lambda-from-aurora-rds-stored-procedure-permissions-issue).
please help!!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code, and let us know which line is giving you the error.

Answer (score 0):

actually i was placing lambda role in parameter group value. replacing with RDS IAM role solve my issue thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/b2b9k4/new_rds_cluster_management_screen_missing_manage/ on which they sugest to add an IAM role for the cluster.

For that go to the RDS Cluster and under *Connectivity & security* tab, go to **Manage IAM roles** and add the desired role.

Note: You may need to enable also IAM DB authentication under *Configuration* tab.

Note2: Reboot your DB instance to apply changes.