# Call lambda from AWS Aurora database trigger

Tags: lambda, amazon-aurora

I want to trigger a lambda when the aurora DB table record update, I went through the AWS documentation and also went through this solution
[Call AWS Lambda from Aurora RDS Stored Procedure Permissions Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659145/call-aws-lambda-from-aurora-rds-stored-procedure-permissions-issue) but I am getting an error saying "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" when I update any record

Answer (score 0):

You may be better just using the [database activity stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/DBActivityStreams.Overview.html) or [DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Kinesis.html), both support writing to Kinesis Data Stream which can in turn then be used to invoke a lambda. Database Activity Stream is only available on certain Aurora instance types but if it is one of the instances you are using then i think that would be the least effort to implement, the most robust and the least impact on your RDS instances themselves.